# Error in solve.default(GAMMA) : Fortran complex functions are not available on this platform

Tags: r, linux, gfortran

I have recently upgraded an old iMac to Ubuntu 22.04 and it is going pretty well. However after running `ape::ace()` in R today I got this error:

```
Error in solve.default(GAMMA) : 
Fortran complex functions are not available on this platform
```

I have googled and cannot find this error being reported before. I have gfortran installed (GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0), but something else must be missing that I should install.

Does anyone have any ideas what the dependency is?

Comment: Related: [r-base: gfortran and gcc disagree on double complex](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/r-base/+bug/1950283). The latest advice (from earlier this month) is to check whether "R has been built without Fortran complex functions" and/or "follow the instructions to download upstream's R packages from CRAN https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/".

Comment: Thank you I reinstalled R using the link you supplied and it solved the issue!